# Tcl/Tk: can't bind  to Escape and Return

Tags: tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

I can't `bind` the `Escape` and `Return` keys in my Tcl/Tk code. The following code reproduces the bug. When I hit `Esc` or `Enter` key I get the following error message:

*Error: can't read "cmd": no such variable*

```tcl
proc OkCancel { cmd } {
  button .${cmd}.ok -text "OK" -command [list myOk $cmd ]
  button .${cmd}.cancel -text "Cancel" -command [list myCancel .$cmd]
  grid .${cmd}.ok .${cmd}.cancel -sticky e

  bind .$cmd <Return> { myOk $cmd ; break }
  bind .$cmd <Escape> { myCancel .${cmd} ; break }
}

proc myOk { cmd } {
  puts "The command name is = $cmd"
}

proc myCancel { arg } {
  destroy $arg
}

proc test { } {
  set cmd "hello"
  toplevel .$cmd
  OkCancel $cmd
}

test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because when an event fires, the script bound to it gets `eval`uated at the global level (as per the [`bind` manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M24)).  That is, in case of your `<Return>` binding, the script `myOk $cmd ; break` will be executed, literally.  Hence, if there exists no variable named "cmd" in the global namespace at the time your script runs, the error you have shown will be triggered.

To fix the problem, there are several ways:

- Make the `$cmd` substitution be evaluated at the time the script is created and bound.  To do this, just replace {} with "" to allow variable substitution, that is, if you'd write `bind .$cmd <Return> " myOk $cmd ; break "` the bound script would be `myOK hello ; break`
- Turn the callback script into a procedure call and pass it explicit parameters, like this: `bind .$cmd <Return> [list mycallback $cmd]` and then make sure you have defined `mycallback` procedure accepting one parameter.  This way you can write generic event handlers which are parameterized by whatever parameters you need at the time of the binding.
- Use `namespace code` or a similar tool to make your script executed in a specified namespace which has the specified variable defined.

In all cases beware that since your $cmd may in certain cases expand to something odd, it's a good idea to protect the whole script from such a situation--that's what `[list ...]` does in the second example (see [this](http://beedub.com/book/3rd/Eval.pdf) for more info).

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation and fixing the bug!

Comment: The `subst` command is preferable instead of `list`. Because `list`can do unnecessary escaping in case of script.

Comment: @GrAnd: Usually no; `list` is generally better than `subst` for generating binding scripts (and other callbacks) because it is far easier to use correctly, _provided_ you're generating a single command. (The question has a trickier case, where I'd use `[list …]\;break` or even get the callback procedures to finish with `return -code break`.)

Comment: @GrAnd: I think you're wrong. `list` is _always_ preferable to `subst` if you're creating a single command. There's no guarantee that `subst` will yield a valid list, but `list` always will.